# Can You Change The Date SourceField In An Excel Slicer Timeline To Another Date SourceField Using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, dashboard, slicers

I have one Slicer Timeline that I use for multiple pivot table reports (each of which is on a separate worksheet).

What I do is simply copy the slicer timeline onto the Reports worksheet and then, using VBA, change the Report Connection to the respective pivot table for that report.

This works fine but the problem I'm running into is the name of the "Date" field in my pivot tables varies:

Date, Date Listed, Date Sold

I'm looking for VBA code that removes the existing Date SourceField in the timeline slicer and updates it to use the Date SourceField used in the target pivot table.

Is this possible? If so, kindly provide a code sample.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the slicer? Have you considered creating a new one instead?

Comment: I have the slicer configured and formatted in multiple ways so I want to use the same one.

Comment: I would suggest create your customized slicer style first. Then create a new slice and apply the style.  https://www.pk-anexcelexpert.com/pivot-table/chapter-15/